# При перемещении костей в pose mode положение и поворот в свойствах не меняется

Tags: анимация, blender

Такая проблема: я перемещаю руки с скелетом в режиме pose mode, но в свойствах объекта не меняются значения ни положения, ни поворота. Из-за этого я не могу сделать анимацию. Однако до этого все работало, пока не применил applyy ко всему чтобы экспортировать.